# How to pass data to your view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**anytime i run this code {{$user->username}} i can get an error below is my code**

My profile controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index($user)
    {
        $user =\App\User::find($user);

        return view('home', [
            '$user'=>$user,]);
    }
}
```

My home.blade.php:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="https://instagram.flos3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/89984222_2767858776654999_2981204085111259136_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.flos3-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=i7OD5CdA7MIAX8KNeXk&oh=bb8370d232e928d467274133a0f14a9e&oe=5EAB5D46" class="rounded-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 pt-5">
        <div><h1>{{ $user->username }}</h1></div>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="pr-5"><strong>300</strong> Posts</div>
            <div class="pr-5"><strong>50k</strong> Followers</div>
            <div class="pr-5"><strong>20</strong> Following</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-4 font-weight-bold">techninjasng.com</div>
        <div >We are global brand with the focus to design digital product for benefit of the </div>
        <div><a href="#">www.techninjasng.com</a></div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: This is simply a typo, the correct syntax is `'user' => $user` (without the $ sign). Generally, you don't want `$` in your strings in PHP, unless you want interpolation. `'$user'` (in single quotes) will be the string `$user`, but `"$user"` (in double quotes) will be whatever `$user` evaluates to (a User model in this case). Read all about it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. Voting to close as typo/syntax error.

Comment: it is just a typo man, convert
'$user'=>$user
to 
'user'=>$user

Answer (score 1):

To render data to view in Laravel as described in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views

your code :

```
return view('home', ['$user'=>$user,]);
```

the correct:

```
return view('home', ['user' => $user]);
```

Comment: i have done that but it didn't work public function index($user)
    {
        $user =\App\User::find($user);

        return view('home', [
            '$user'=>$user,]);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Answer was already made but just an advice which could really help.

You can use dependency injection and convert your **index** method to this

```php
public function index(\App\User $user)
{
    return view('home', compact('user'));
}
```

This code will do the same as you wanted but it is much cleaner

Also I think method should be called **show** and not **index** which is used to get list of items

Comment: i have but still getting the same eror

Answer (score 0):

I have found through a friend

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <img src="https://instagram.flos3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/89984222_2767858776654999_2981204085111259136_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.flos3-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=i7OD5CdA7MIAX8KNeXk&oh=bb8370d232e928d467274133a0f14a9e&oe=5EAB5D46" class="rounded-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 pt-5">
        <div><h1>{{ Auth::user->username }}</h1></div>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="pr-5"><strong>300</strong> Posts</div>
            <div class="pr-5"><strong>50k</strong> Followers</div>
            <div class="pr-5"><strong>20</strong> Following</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-4 font-weight-bold">techninjasng.com</div>
        <div >We are global brand with the focus to design digital product for benefit of the </div>
        <div><a href="#">www.techninjasng.com</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem was from the view template in home.blade.php. I didn't use the Auth to authenticate the user from my database that will be displayed on the profile page

Answer (score 0):

this is syntax Error you shout do that

```
    return view('home', compact('user'));
```

or
this that will help you if you want pass a lot of data in your view

```
$InformationTosendTotheView=Array(
"users"=>$users
```

...
);
        return view('home',InformationTosendTotheView);